# libwebsockets vs. WebSockets++

Tags: c++, c, websocket

I'm going to make a realtime multiplayer game using the WebSocket technology. However, I am unsure which server implementation I should use. I've found two mature (enough) libraries that suit my needs. libwebsockets and WebSockets++.

Did anyone try them out? Can someone point out the main differences between these two libraries?

Comment: I might be wrong but it looks like those libraries are just for HTTP. If you are making a multiplayer game, you want raw sockets (usually UDP for performance) not HTTP sockets. Try something like `Boost Asio` or the raw sockets for your OS.

Comment: Websockets != HTTP. I *do* want websockets for my game.

Comment: for me, it's the easiest to install, but i'm just trying to make a super fast webapp.  you probably need all the speed you can get.  websockets++ is probably your ideal route.  libwebsockets looks easy to install on fedora, so that's my choice

Comment: But WebSockets NEEDS http.

Comment: WebSockets are HTTP(TCP) on the client side (HTTP part is limited until handshake only). TCP on the server's side (which you will write). You do not absolutely need to use UDP but it has higher performance rating if your game will be played by A LOT. (TCP probably won't be a problem)
Both are good, go with the one that is maintained, looks well structured to you, and is well documented.

Comment: libwebsockets has a default HTTP protocol but you can add custom protocols handled by separate callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [QWebSockets](http://kurtpattyn.github.io/QWebSockets/), which is written in Qt and works both for clients and servers.